# Prevent reshape2 from converting column headings to numbers

Tags: r, matrix, reshape2

I am trying to create a lookup table from an actual distance matrix for US zip code locations using the GoogleMaps model shown on Lars Relund Nielsen's [webpage](http://www.research.relund.dk/?p=580). The Zip codes in the Northeastern US begin with a "0" and therefore get dropped when reshape2 converts the matrix from wide to long as described on his page.

example matrix of distances (km) between 5 Zip codes:

```
    mdat <- matrix(c(0.000, 113.288, 145.986, 126.271, 368.354
             ,103.988, 0.000, 69.637, 49.922, 294.386
             ,144.851, 69.285, 0.000, 25.547, 244.024
             ,124.531, 48.965, 25.245, 0.000, 258.729
             ,368.346, 295.159, 243.478, 258.598, 0.000)
           , nrow = 5
           , ncol = 5
           , byrow = TRUE,
           dimnames = list(c("01014", "01747", "02144", "02453", "04040"),
                           c("01014", "01747", "02144", "02453", "04040")))
Looks like this (all well and good);

#       01014   01747   02144   02453   04040
#01014   0.000 113.288 145.986 126.271 368.354
#01747 103.988   0.000  69.637  49.922 294.386
#02144 144.851  69.285   0.000  25.547 244.024
#02453 124.531  48.965  25.245   0.000 258.729
#04040 368.346 295.159 243.478 258.598   0.000
```

But when I reshape the Matrix to a lookup table it converts the row/col names to a number dropping the leading zero from the Zip code.

```
#reshape into a table of distances
library(reshape2)
dat<-(melt(mdat))
dat
colnames(dat)<-c("from","to","km")
head(dat)

  from   to      km
1 1014 1014   0.000
2 1747 1014 103.988
3 2144 1014 144.851
4 2453 1014 124.531
5 4040 1014 368.346
6 1014 1747 113.288
```

I am hoping to get;

```
from   to      km
1 01014 01014   0.000
2 01747 01014 103.988
3 02144 01014 144.851
4 02453 01014 124.531
5 04040 01014 368.346
6 01014 01747 113.288
```

Any thoughts on how I can keep reshape2 from converting the the Zip codes to a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include as.is=TRUE in your `melt` function:

```
dat<-(melt(mdat, as.is=TRUE))
colnames(dat)<-c("from","to","km")
```

This will keep the column names as strings through the melting process.

Comment: @Imo - When I run your suggestion in my example provided, this does not seem to work, the "0" is still dropped in the "dat" data set..thoughts? - maybe there is another way, without using reshape2 - I am up for suggestions?

Comment: @RobertWhite Are you sure? I have run the same code (just copying and pasting your mdat matrix code and then my dat melting code) on two different machines and get the leading zeros on both.

Comment: @Imo - interesting when I run it in Rstudio it removes the leading "0", but when run in R - it works!...I didn't realize, and I probably should have indicated Rstudio in my question,  there was a difference?

Comment: @RobertWhite That is really strange. I ran the code through rstudio on both machines, both copying directly into console and also copying into script and running from there. It shouldn't matter, but do you have the latest version of rstudio and reshape2?

Comment: @Imo, you solved the mystery - reshape2 out of date! Thank you for your help!